# Amazon Connect Contact Flow - Transfer to a SIP URI/SIP Destination

Tags: amazon-connect

Is it possibly, from within an Amazon Connect contact flow, to Transfer to a SIP URI instead of [Transferring to a Phone Number](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/transfer-to-phone-number.html) via the PSTN? How have others handled this? The SIP destination offers much lower costs.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not currently transfer or connect to SIP or other IP telephony endpoints using features of Amazon Connect. PSTN connectivity is the only option at this point.